# MSBuild Wildcard in ItemGroup sometimes expands and sometimes doesn't

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild

I have an msbuild script that I'm trying to run through jenkins and it is sometimes successful and sometimes fails based on a wild card expansion. This is the body of the script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="FinalCopy">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Dev</Configuration>
    <BuildPlatform Condition=" '$(BuildPlatform)' == '' ">Any CPU</BuildPlatform>
    <DeployDir>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Deploy_$(Configuration)</DeployDir>
    <BuildOutput>$(DeployDir)\Build_Output</BuildOutput>
    <AdminDir>$(DeployDir)\Admin</AdminDir>
    <TempDir>$(DeployDir)\Temp</TempDir>
    <SolutionFile>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)MyApplication.sln</SolutionFile>
    <NUnitConsole>C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console.exe</NUnitConsole>
    <AdminConfigLocation>$(ConfigRepo)\Admin\$(Configuration)</AdminConfigLocation>
    <WebConfig>$(AdminConfigLocation)\Web.config</WebConfig>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <TestConfigs Include="$(AdminConfigLocation)\MyApplication.*.Tests.dll.config" />
    <TestResultsPath Include="$(DeployDir)\TestResults.xml" />
    <ProjectsToBuild Include="$(SolutionFile)">
        <AdditionalProperties>
            VisualStudioVersion=$(VisualStudioVersion);
            Configuration=$(Configuration);
            OutputPath=$(BuildOutput);
            WebPublishMethod=FileSystem;
            publishUrl=$(TempDir);
            DeleteExistingFiles=True;
            DeployOnBuild=True;
            DeployTarget=WebPublish;
            PublishProfile=$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath);
            Platform=$(BuildPlatform)
        </AdditionalProperties>
    </ProjectsToBuild>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
     <TestDlls Include="$(BuildOutput)\MyApplication.*.Tests.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="FinalCopy" DependsOnTargets="RunUnitTests">
    <Message Text="Moving files to final destination" Importance="high" />
    <Exec Command='move "$(TempDir)" "$(AdminDir)"' />
    <Message Text="Finished moving files to final destination" Importance="high" />
  </Target>

  <!-- This target runs the unit tests and publishes the results -->
  <Target Name="RunUnitTests" DependsOnTargets="CopyTestConfigs">
    <Exec Command='"$(NUnitConsole)" "%(TestDlls.Identity)" /xml="@(TestResultsPath)"' />
  </Target>

  <!-- This target copies config files for tests from our config repo -->
  <Target Name="CopyTestConfigs" DependsOnTargets="CopyWebConfig">
    <Message Text="Copying test configuration files" Importance="high" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(TestConfigs)" DestinationFolder="$(BuildOutput)" />
    <Message Text="Finished copying test configuration files" Importance="high" />
  </Target>

  <!-- This target copies the web.config files from our config repo -->
  <Target Name="CopyWebConfig" DependsOnTargets="DeployAdmin">
    <Message Text="Copying web configuration files" Importance="high" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(WebConfig)" DestinationFolder="$(TempDir)" />
    <Message Text="Finished copying web configuration files" Importance="high" />
  </Target>

  <!-- This target builds and deploys the admin application to a temp folder -->
  <Target Name="DeployAdmin" DependsOnTargets="Init">
    <Message Text="Copying admin files" Importance="high" />
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectsToBuild)" />
    <Message Text="Finished copying admin files" Importance="high" />
  </Target>

  <!-- This target creates the directory in which deployment files are going to be held -->
  <Target Name="Init" DependsOnTargets="Clean">
    <Message Text="Making deployment directory" Importance="high" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(DeployDir)" />
    <Message Text="Finished making deployment directory" Importance="high" />
  </Target>

  <!-- This target removes any existing build/deploy artifacts -->
  <Target Name="Clean">
    <Message Text="Removing existing deployment directory" Importance="high" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(DeployDir)" />
    <Message Text="Finished removing existing deployment directory" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The line that is causing problems is this:

```
<Exec Command='"$(NUnitConsole)" "%(TestDlls.Identity)" /xml="@(TestResultsPath)"'
```

`%(TestDlls.Identity)` sometimes gets expanded into an ItemArray and sometimes does not and I'm completely stumped as to why. It seems that if I delete my jenkins workspace folder and try to build, it fails because of the above problem. Very randomly, if I manually create any file (say, an empty text file) in `$(DeployDir)` and then run the jenkins job, it runs as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried running this locally in a controlled environment? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, I tried running this on a local instance of jenkins and I get the same results. This is the output I'm seeing:

    `RunUnitTests:
      "C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console.exe" "" /xml="C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\admin test\Deploy_Dev\TestResults.xml"`

You can see that the item group is not getting expanded and instead it is outputting an empty string **""**

Comment: so when you execute this locally, what do you find  in `$(DeployDir)` during the build? I suspect it does not get populated for some reason (maybe, your build fails or puts binaries into some other directory - set build verbosity to detailed/diagnostic and examine the logs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to this problem, which actually turns out to be a cleaner solution overall. I changed the target named RunUnitTests:

```
<!-- This target runs the unit tests and publishes the results -->
<Target Name="RunUnitTests" DependsOnTargets="CopyTestConfigs">
    <ItemGroup>
        <TestDlls Include="$(BuildOutput)\MyApplication.*.Tests.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(NUnitConsole)&quot; @(TestDlls->'&quot;%(FullPath)&quot;', ' ') /xml=&quot;@(TestResultsPath)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

The benefit to this is that all of the tests (which are in different dlls) are passed into the call to NUnit at once and results for all of the tests are outputted in the results file. I've tested this out both locally and our build server and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <NuGetPackageConfigs Include="../**/packages.config " />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="LoadNuGetPackages">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="%0ARetrieving packages for %(NuGetPackageConfigs.Identity)" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Comm>nuget install %(NuGetPackageConfigs.Identity) -o packages"</Comm>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(Comm)" />
  </Target>
```

When I run localy from jenkins working dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\project\workspace, 
msbuild does not resolve ../**/packages.config. 
When I run it from C:\Program Files (x86)\a\project it works

I changed to

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <NuGetPackageConfigs Include="../*/*/packages.config " />
    <NuGetPackageConfigs Include="../*/packages.config " />
  </ItemGroup>
```

It works, nut it is not the same, still no idea what is going on.